# Is it possible to do update/insert to multiple document with one query at MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Let say, I have a collection

```
{"id":"1", "count":5},
{"id":"2", "count":8}
```

I would like to check if id 1, 2 and 3 exist in the collection.
If the id not exist => insert a new document to the collection. Eg: {"id":"3", "count":1}
If the id exists => increment count by 1

I tried this, but failed.

```
db.my_collection.update(
    { id : { $in : ["1", "2", "3"] }},
    { $inc : { id : 1 } },
    { upsert : true }
);
```

Could someone give me some hints?

I expect the result will be:

```
{"id":"1", "count":6},
{"id":"2", "count":9},
{"id":"3", "count":1}
```

Comment: did you try {multi: true } and what is the version ? This will work for mongodb 2.2+                                                                                                           see following docs https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this by using multi parameter. Refer to following link for more info. [click here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)